# Disable DateParseHandling on document deserialization

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have documents on DocumentDB that store a date on [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). These dates are stored as strings:

```
{
  "CreatedOn": "2016-04-15T14:54:40Z",
  "Title": "Some title",
  "id": "xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
}
```

We are using the latest [Azure DocumentDB SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) (1.7.0) on a **WebAPI that uses ASP.NET Core**.

The C# class that maps our documents have the "CreatedOn" property as a *string*.

```
public class Item
{
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when we read a document and the SDK deserializes it, it tries to convert it to a *DateTime* and then **back** to a *string*. Resulting in:

```
{
  "CreatedOn": "15/04/2016 14:54:40",
  "Title": "Some title",
  "id": "xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
}
```

What I need is to the SDK to leave the **values untouched**. I tried setting the default SerializerSettings to avoid the date parsing:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts =>
{
    opts.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.None;
});
```

But it didn't work.

I tried using a [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) attribute but the problem is that on the ReadJson override method, the reader already parsed the string value to a DateTime.

```
class StringJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        reader.Value <-- already a parsed DateTime
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this auto parsing?

Comment: Matias, is this an WebAPI mapping issue instead of a DocumentDB issue? If you're storing as string and reading back as string, then the DocumentDB SDK will not perform any translations.

Comment: Hi @Aravind, this is a DocumentDB issue. The result I'm showing is when I call the [CreateDocumentQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.linq.documentqueryable.createdocumentquery.aspx) method on the SDK. DocumentDB uses Json.Net internally, the problem is that they [don't expose the JsonSettings](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6422364-allow-me-to-set-jsonserializersettings) and Json.Net automatically tries to parse a date-like string to a DateTime, even when the mapped class has a string attribute.

Comment: The [DateParseHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm) setting of Json.Net has that goal, to deactivate that auto-parsing logic, but setting it on the global level seems to have no effect on how DocumentDB uses it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found a workaround, since the [JsonSettings are not accesible](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6422364-allow-me-to-set-jsonserializersettings) at this time, I'm using a JsonConverter:

```
public class StringJsonConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return true;
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
       }

       public override bool CanRead
       {
           get { return true; }
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           if (reader.ValueType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
           {
               return ((DateTime)reader.Value).ToIso8601Date();
           }
           if (reader.ValueType.Equals(typeof(DateTimeOffset)))
           {
               return ((DateTimeOffset)reader.Value).DateTime.ToIso8601Date();
           }
           return (string)reader.Value;
       }        
   }
```

With this simple extension:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    private const string DateTimeFormat = "{0}-{1}-{2}T{3}:{4}:{5}Z";

    public static string ToIso8601Date(this DateTime date)
    {
        if (date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return string.Format(
            DateTimeFormat,
            date.Year,
            PadLeft(date.Month),
            PadLeft(date.Day),
            PadLeft(date.Hour),
            PadLeft(date.Minute),
            PadLeft(date.Second));
    }
     private static string PadLeft(int number)
    {
        if (number < 10)
        {
            return string.Format("0{0}", number);
        }

        return number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON serializer settings can now be passed straight to DocumentClient [constuctors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient__ctor_System_Uri_System_Security_SecureString_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_ConnectionPolicy_System_Nullable_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_ConsistencyLevel__), which allows for the flexibility you required.